# npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-43-generic

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this error when I try to npm due to nodejs installation. I have done what I could but still can't work it out.

As u can see am using linuxbrew which I thought would help but still no way. Any suggestions here?

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-43-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/ericel/.linuxbrew/Cellar/node/6.7.0/bin/node" "/home/ericel/.linuxbrew/bin/npm" "cache" "clean"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! path /home/ericel/.npm/@angular/common
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/home/ericel/.npm/@angular/common'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/home/ericel/.npm/@angular/common'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/ericel/.npm/@angular/common' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ericel/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo

Answer (score 0):

It has `permission denied` problem. Try to run that installation with `sudo` or root user.